# C# group by to eliminate duplicates

Tags: c#, linq, group-by

Im working with a large dataset of point of interest (POI) which all have Lat/Long values.

I want to filter out POIs that are in close proximity to each other. I think that to achieve this I can round the Lat/Long down to X decimal places and group by the results (or call `Distinct()` or whatever)...

I have written a little LINQ statement which doesnt seem to do what I want,

```
 var l1 = (from p in PointsOfInterest where p.IsVisibleOnMap select p).Distinct(new EqualityComparer()).ToList();
```

where `EqualityComparer` is

```
public class EqualityComparer : IEqualityComparer<PointOfInterest>
{
    public bool Equals(PointOfInterest x, PointOfInterest y)
    {
        return Math.Round(x.Latitude.Value, 4) == Math.Round(y.Latitude.Value, 4) && 
            Math.Round(x.Longitude.Value, 4) == Math.Round(y.Latitude.Value, 4);
    }

    public int GetHashCode(PointOfInterest obj)
    {
        return obj.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

but the Equals method never seems to get called?!?

Any thoughts on the best way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Equals()` never gets called because `GetHashCode()` returns different values for any two objects because you are using `GetHashCode()` defined in `System.Object` class .
You'll need to implement GetHashCode() a little differently.

try something like

```
public int GetHashCode(PointOfInterest obj)
{
    return obj.Longitude.Value.GetHashCode() ^ obj.Latitude.Value.GetHashCode();
}
```

Comment: hmm, so for this equality comparer, maybe return 0 as hash code would do the trick

Answer (score 3):

This is the problem:

```
public int GetHashCode(PointOfInterest obj)
{
    return obj.GetHashCode();
}
```

You'll have to override `GetHashCode()` appropriately as well, probably currently all items are considered different because the hash code doesn't match.

From MSDN for [`IEqualityComparer.GetHashCode()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.iequalitycomparer.gethashcode.aspx):

> Implement this method to provide
>   customized hash codes for
>   objects,corresponding to the
>   customized equality comparison
>   provided by the Equals method.

Answer (score 1):

> Any thoughts on the best way to do this?

Simply:

```
IEnumerable<PointOfInterest> result =
  from p in PointsOfInterest
  where p.IsVisibleOnMap
  group p by new
  {
    Latitude = Math.Round(p.Latitude.Value, 4),
    Longitude = Math.Round(p.Longitude.Value, 4)
  } into g
  let winner = g.First()
  select winner;
```